# I want to create counter variable by for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to create counter variable (int ball=0)but it does not work.

ideally, I want to keep record ball =1 ,ball=2,,,,, every times I got ball input

I want it to display fourball! in 4th.

```
ball → ball!
ball → ball!
ball → ball!
ball → fourball!
```

but now every time ball displayed!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("type number 5~7");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String number = sc.nextLine();
        int u = Integer.parseInt(number);
        System.out.println(u + "times will be played ");
        for (int i=0; i<u; i++) {
            String result = sc.nextLine();
            if (result.equals("ball")) {
                int ball = 1;
                ball ++;
                System.out.println(ball);
                if (ball >= 4) {
                    System.out.println("fourball!");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ball!");
                }
            }

        }//for終わり



            /*else if (result.equals("strike")) {
                for (int strike=0; strike<=5; strike++) {
                    if (strike >= 2) {
                        System.out.println("out!");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("strike!");
                    }
                }//if
            }//else if 
            else{
                System.out.println("type strike or ball");
            }

             */
        //}//for
    }//main

}//Main
```

Comment: You always assign `ball` to `1` in the loop

Answer (score 0):

just set the ball counter outside of the for loop like that

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("type number 5~7");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String number = sc.nextLine();
        int u = Integer.parseInt(number);
        System.out.println(u + "times will be played ");
        int ball = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<u; i++) {
            String result = sc.nextLine();
            if (result.equals("ball")) {
                ball ++;
                System.out.println(ball);
                if (ball >= 4) {
                    System.out.println("fourball!");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ball!");
                }
            }

        }
```